# SQL query debugging required

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, dataset, sql

i am working in winforms with C#. heres my code

```
query = "SELECT max(Appointment_Time) FROM Appointments WHERE (Appointment_Status = 'D')";
dset = db.GetRecords(query,"Appointments");
ctime_Label.Text = dset.Tables["Appointments"].Rows[0]["Appointment_Time"].ToString();
```

**db.GETRecords** is a function of the class that provides me sql-services, simply returns me a dataset. i keep getting the error "the column 'Appointment_Time' doesnot belong to the table Appointments" which is stupid cuz

- when i am inserting the values its
  working fine.
- when i am NOT using
  max(Appointment_Time) function it is
  working fine

wha is the problem here.. i think there is something to do with the max() function. Any suggestion or alternative for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the query in SQL Server and see what you get.

Now try:

```
 SELECT max(Appointment_Time) as A_Time FROM Appointments WHERE (Appointment_Status = 'D')";
```

and then

```
 ctime_Label.Text = dset.Tables["Appointments"].Rows[0]["A_Time"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 6):

When you apply a function in the SELECT clause the server has to choose a name for the resulting column, this usually reflects what the function is doing - something like `max(Appointment_Time)`.  The fields used as arguments to the function appear to be 'hidden'.  This is why the field `Appointment_Time` is not visible to the calling code in your case.

You should specify what you want the aggregated field to be called in the SQL using `AS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT max(Appointment_Time) AS Max_Appointment_Time
FROM Appointments WHERE (Appointment_Status = 'D')
```

Then refer to the field as `Max_Appointment_Time` in the calling code.  You can use the same name as the source field if you like.

Comment: thnx to you as well boy.. i chose on FCFS first come fist serve basis